# Is the function $f(x_1,x_2) := (x_1^2+x_2^2) \sin(1/\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$ differentiable at $(x_1,\,x_2)=(0,\,0)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is the function $$f(x_1,x_2) := (x_1^2+x_2^2) \sin(1/\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$$ differentiable at $(x_1,\,x_2)=(0,\,0)$? How to prove it. I have already found that the partial derivatives $\partial_{x_1}f$ and $\partial_{x_2}f$ are not continuous at $(0,\,0)$, so I don't know how to continue my proof.

Answer (score 1):

In order to examine differentiability at the origin you should test whether $$f(x_1,x_2)=f(0,0)+x_1f_{x_1}(0,0)+x_2f_{x_2}(0,0)+\mathcal{o} \left(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \right) $$
Since the partial derivatives are both zero, this boils down to whether

$$\lim_{(x_1,x_2) \to (0,0)} \frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2) \sin 1/\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}=0 $$ or not. Using the squeeze law gives an affirmative answer to this question, since for all $(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ with $(x_1, x_2)$ you have
$$0\leq \left| \frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2) \sin 1/\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\right|\leq \left| \frac{x_1^2+x_2^2 }{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\right|.$$

Comment: @GitGud Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer a little bit? You can of course roll back if you don't like my edit.

Comment: @GitGud go ahead